# c# wcf expand one to many returns only 1 entity

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, sap-smp

I'm using WCF to implements SAP OData service.
Everything works fine, except some navigation properties return only one entity when queried with expand, although they are defined as 1 to * cardinality :-(

I've already changed the WCF merging to Overwrite, but still no chance to get all entities :-(

I traced that the result string from server contains all entities, but somehow the WCF framework cuts them? It seem's that it always shows the last entity!

Is there a certain setting?

I'm using WCF within a Win AppStore App (C# XAML)

regards
Meex

Comment: Some code would be really useful here. Can you provide a sample of what you've tried?

Comment: Do you set page size for the navigated entity set?